# After I load a file with Hebrew text from raw folder it is not displayed correctly, how did I fix it?

Tags: java, android

This is my code

```
public class Blogs extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seriously);
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream iStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.minzelostam);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        try {
            while ((line = bReader.readLine())!=null){
                finalString.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLongText);
        tv.setText(finalString);
    }   
}
```

And this is the result on the screen

[image: enter link description here]

The problem is writing in Hebrew, I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2d8p27c.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Either the file wasn't saved with Unicode UTF-8 encoding (possily saved with Windoes NotePad?), or you aren't using a font which includes the Hebraic glyphs to display the results.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task to resolve a few years ago. I downloaded a hebrew font and added to the assets of the project. Then loaded that font file and set the returned typeface to the textview I was setting the hebrew text on. Try a similar approach. [Here's a font that might help you](https://code.google.com/p/israelpack/downloads/detail?name=DroidSansHebrew.ttf)

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.dolev.jinjer;
```

public class Blogs extends Activity{

```
Typeface tf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seriously);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DroidSansHebrew.ttf‬");
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream iStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.minzelostam);
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(iStream));

    try {
        while ((line = bReader.readLine())!=null){
            finalString.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLongText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    tv.setText(finalString);
}
```

}

still dosent work :(

Comment: Create a fonts folder insdide the assets folder and put the ".ttf" file in that folder.

Comment: but you are not specifying the full path of the font file. `tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "/fonts/DroidSansHebrew.ttf‬");`